# Error: Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=4.5.0.0

Tags: asp.net, dll

I am getting that error, but i am not using that version of `newtonsoft`
I am using version 10.0.3.

[image: Error]

How can I find what dll is using it? or where it's coming from?

I already tried:

- binding redirect in web.config, look like that: `oldVersion="0.0.0.0-10.0.0.0" newVersion="10.0.0.0"`
- cleaning old versions installed at C:\Users\USERNAME.nuget\packages\
- Cleaned the solution and rebuilt it

Comment: try uninstall nuget package and install it again

Comment: thanks, but it didn't work